# How can I change the default URL in Web App?

Tags: node.js, web, web-applications

So I have a normal Blank Node.js Web Application. Every time I execute the program the default URL/page is "localhost:1337". Where can I set the default URl so when I execute the programm the first page which should be shown is for example "localhost:1337/mydefaultpage.html"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go under Project -> Right click-> Properties ->  Set Launch Url

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using some framework like [Express.js](http://expressjs.com) . If you are, then, please refer to Express.js routing [guide](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html). 
Although you can implement all these in pure Node, it's recommended to use a HTTP framework when developing web apps or API's.

Answer (score 0):

Change the title in javascript and then click on the live server then you will get it
I think this is the answer for this